# Setting cookie on CORS request with wildcard origin

Tags: javascript, ajax, cookies, cors

We operate a public API that can be called from any origin. To allow the calls we set all CORS headers to wildcards and we also set the allow-credentials header.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

Usually we do the authentication via a custom HTTP-header but for one special call we also accept cookies. The reason behind this is our file download we provide via the API. We first download the file via AJAX showing a progress indicator. As part of this call we set all cache headers that the file is placed in the browser cache. After the download into the browser cache is finished we add a hidden iframe to the page pointing to the file we just prefetched. This way we want to enforce the browser to normally "download" the file from the cache.

In case something with the browser cache goes wrong and the browser makes a HTTP call to the API, we want to set a cookie as part of our file request containing the authentication token. This way the browser will send the cookie when opening the file in the iframe. And here lies the problem: You cannot have the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header set to wildcard and still use the `withCredentials` setting. For instance Chrome will show the error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load `https://myapihost/v1/file/1234`. Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: A wildcard '`*`'
>   cannot be used in the '`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`' header when the
>   credentials flag is true. Origin '`http://myclientapp`' is therefore not
>   allowed access. The credentials mode of an XMLHttpRequest is
>   controlled by the `withCredentials` attribute.

Is there some good way to handle this scenario? The only solution I can think of, is to return always the origin sent by the client in the response header.

I understand the security aspects that it is not a good idea to open up your resources to any origin in general, but in the case of our public API there might be various client apps on any origin. Sadly there is no way to tell a browser to send a particular header when opening an iframe.

I'm currently also considering [download.js](http://danml.com/download.html) to download the prefetched files but before starting a bigger rework I want to hear your opinion.

Comment: Having `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials ` for this particular resource always return the origin sent by the client. If you are setting it only for this particular resource, and this resource doesn’t have the ability to run script (which seems to be the case), there is no a security risk (e.g., no risk of unexpected privilege escalation that’d allow an attacker to run script with the user’s privileges to get access to firewalled resources). So I think you really don’t have anything to worry about with regard to security if you always return the client origin in this particular case.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I went for the solution to send the origin back to the client. Now the client does not complain anymore and I can properly set the cookies on API level.

Comment: Hey, I know this is old, but do you have any more details on how you solved this issue? I'm having a similar problem. What do you mean by sending the origin back to the client? Did this allow you to keep the wildcard in your CORS?

Comment: On the API server we do not return the `*` wildcard anymore. We return to the client the exact origin that he sent us. This means when a client makes a call and sends us `Origin: mydomain.com` in the request, we return a header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: mydomain.com` instead of a wildcard in the response.